# Use RestTemplate with object as data and application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to post an object (e.g. not a `MultiValueMap`) via a `RestTemplate` with the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. When I try to do so ...

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
HttpEntity request;

headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)

// data is some generic type
request = new HttpEntity<>(data, headers);

// clazz is the Class<T> being returned
restTemplate.exchange(url, method, request, clazz)
```

... I get the following error:

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.whatever.MyRequestPayload] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]

Here is what I see within `restTemplate.getMessageConverters()`:

[image: message converters]

*Why don't I want to provide a `MultiValueMap`?* Two reasons:

1. this is general purpose code which is used to send requests to multiple endpoints, so adding an overload specifically for `x-www-form-urlencoded` will only complicate things
2. it doesn't seem like I should have to -- I just don't know which HttpMessageConverter needs to be used to support converting objects to a `x-www-form-urlencoded` string

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I ended up having to write a custom HTTP message converter which takes any object and writes it out as www-form-urlencoded content to the request body:

### Usage

```java
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(...);

template.getMessageConverters().add(new ObjectToUrlEncodedConverter(mapper));
```

### ObjectToUrlEncodedConverter

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ObjectToUrlEncodedConverter implements HttpMessageConverter
{
    private static final String Encoding = "UTF-8";

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectToUrlEncodedConverter(ObjectMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class clazz, MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class clazz, MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return getSupportedMediaTypes().contains(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes()
    {
        return Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    }

    @Override
    public Object read(Class clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws HttpMessageNotReadableException
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Object o, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws HttpMessageNotWritableException
    {
        if (o != null)
        {
            String body = mapper
                .convertValue(o, UrlEncodedWriter.class)
                .toString();

            try
            {
                outputMessage.getBody().write(body.getBytes(Encoding));
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // if UTF-8 is not supporter then I give up
            }
        }
    }

    private static class UrlEncodedWriter
    {
        private final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void write(String name, Object property) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
        {
            if (out.length() > 0)
            {
                out.append("&");
            }

            out
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(name, Encoding))
                .append("=");

            if (property != null)
            {
                out.append(URLEncoder.encode(property.toString(), Encoding));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return out.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please can you add example for the mapper object ?

Comment: @Esameldean just create an instance of ObjectMapper like this:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ObjectToUrlEncodedConverter(mapper));

Answer (score 17):

Reason: there is no converter can convert your java object into request body in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Solution1: create this kind of converter, as what @Josh M. posts.

Solution2: convert your java object into `MultiValueMap`, and there is already a converter named `FormHttpMessageConverter` in spring boot which will convert `MultiValueMap` into request body in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format automatically.

So in solution2, all you need is to convert your java object into `MultiValueMap`:

```
        MultiValueMap<String, String> bodyPair = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
        bodyPair.add(K1, V1);
        bodyPair.add(K2, V2);
        bodyPair.add(K3, V3);
        ...
```

`K1`, `V1`, `K2`, `V2`, ..., means the field names and corresponding values in your java object. All the fields you declared in your java class need to be added. If there are too many fields, consider using Java Reflection.

Comment: This is the better answer with newer Spring-Boot versions in 2023

Answer (score 5):

You can try use https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(...);
template.getMessageConverters().add(new org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.FormHttpMessageConverter());
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried something like adding `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to the `RestTemplate`

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(getMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter getMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
    return mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
}
```

Comment: It's already there, check the screenshot. I'll try adding it for the specific media type.

Comment: The supported media in the default mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter only supports json. Mohamed's answer add another converter that supports MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED. But I doubt that if ObjectMapper can convert objects into x-www-form-urlencoded body or not.

Comment: I think you have to write a class to implement HttpMessageConverter<MyRequestPayload>

Comment: Right, I did this and it comes out as a JSON string in the body, not www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm quite curious why you don't just write a static util method to convert MyRequestPayload instance to MultiValueMap instance?

Comment: This is just one payload example. I don't want to write a converter for each payload type, needs to be generic.

Comment: Is it possible to write a util method using reflection to get all field names and values on an object, and then set them into MultiValueMap?

Comment: @Duncan Yes, I just did this and am about to post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` then you might get such errors. Also WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated from Spring 5.x.x. Try using the `WebMvcConfigurer`. Once done you will have to override:

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use FormHttpMessageConverter for content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as below and send data in RestTemplate post method for body as MultiValueMap<String, String>

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg name="requestFactory" ref="bufferingClientHttpRequestFactory" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="responeErrorHandler" />
    <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Java Config Version

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();          
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    return restTemplate 
}
```